# How can I set default locale based on domain extension in symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, localization, locale, symfony4

Let's say I have two domains, example.com and example.eu, they both point to the same host, but based on domain extension I want to set different locale/language.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I see here 2 possible solutions.

1st:
You can make it on only 1 domain and on the second one you can add redirecting to the "main" domain with some GET data... for example: example.eu will redirect you to example.com/index.php?lang=en

2nd:
You can take the URL and remove the domain. example: You remove "example" from "example.com"